# Multidimensional each

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array

How would I do something like below?

```
[
    'foo'
    ['bar', 'baz'],
    [
        'one',
        ['two', 'three']
    ]
].each { |word| puts word }

# I want this to return:

foo
bar
baz
one
two
three
```

Comment: Should there be a comma after `'foo'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to flatten the array and still achieve the desired functionality, you can do something like:

```
irb(main):016:0> array = [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]]
=> [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]]
irb(main):017:0> (traverser = lambda { |list| list.respond_to?(:each) ? list.each(&traverser) : puts(list) })[array]
1
2
3
4
5
6
=> [1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]]
```

Comment: I really like this! This is more of what I was asking for.

Comment: No problem! If you want to get more clever, check out: http://github.com/evansenter/y - an implementation of the Y-combinator in Ruby (note: Most rubies are not tail-call optimized, so with deep nesting this can have performance issues). Then you can:

`Y([1, [2, 3], [4, [5, 6]]]) { |recurser, list| list.respond_to?(:each) ? list.each(&recurser) : puts(list) }`

The difference being no variable assignment (a la 'traverser' in the example above). :]

Answer (score 3):

Could you use `flatten`?

```
[
    'foo'
    ['bar', 'baz'],
    [
        'one',
        ['two', 'three']
    ]
].flatten.each { |word| puts word }
```

`flatten` will return a copy of the array, so the original won't be modified.
It's also fully recursive so it doesn't matter how many arrays-within-arrays you have.

Comment: puts, if given an array, will print each element of the array on a separate line.  Therefore, `a = [...] ; puts a.flatten` can, if desired, replace the `each` loop.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way:

```
words = ['foo',['bar', 'baz'],['one',['two', 'three']]]
words.flatten.each{ |word| puts word }
```